# WAMP Apache HTTP Server debugging issue

Tags: php, wamp

I'm using **wamp version 2.2** For every PHP Page in my project it loads fine. However, when I attempt to go to one specific page, I get the following **Windows Error**:

```
Apache HTTP Server has encountered a problem and needs to close.
```

I have no idea how to debug this or provide the Stackoverflow community with valid data to use for assistance.

If anyone can assist/direct me in solving this, i would be appreciative. I can provide any information needed.

I do know that this specific page reflects a database table i recently updated. The table looks fine to me.

Comment: Can you post here the Server and other useful logs? And when you ask, please write what you've tried.

Comment: There is no error in the error log and the access log does not even show me requesting this page.

Comment: Could you post the contents of the file? Does it happen with files that have similar content?

Comment: I seemed to have resolved it by deleting and reloading the file. Thanks

Comment: Post that as an answer and mark it as an answer. Do not add [solved] or other stuff to the title of the post. Mark the answer.